# How to fix an error, Error in UseMethod("evaluate") : no applicable method for 'evaluate' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Tags: r

I am having trouble in fixing this error while performing SDM:

```
Error in UseMethod("evaluate") : 
  no applicable method for 'evaluate' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

I am trying to evaluate my Maxent model with this command:

```
e <- evaluate(pres_test, backg_test, xm, predictors)
```

but receive the above error. How can I solve this?

Comment: `evaluate` is not a function in base R. What package(s) are you using? What are you call it on - what are `pres_test`, `backg_test`, `xm`, and `predictors`?

Comment: Assuming you're using the `dismo` package, then the documentation says the first 2 arguments, `x` and `y`, need to be either `matrix` or `SpatialPoints*` class objects. My best guess is that at least one of `pres_test` or `backg_test` objects is a data frame, and you need to convert it to a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`. Check the `class()` of your inputs and make sure it matches what the `?evaluate` documentation says you need.

Comment: The "no applicable method..." error arises for generic functions in R.  A generic function in R is a function that produces different outputs depending on the class (type of object) of the argument passed to the function's first parameter.  What R is trying to tell you with this error message is that the function (method) "evaluate" doesn't have a specified behavior for data.frames.  So @GregorThomas is correct that `pres_test` is likely a data.frame when it needs to be some other type of object. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-methods